# error when i call an method with ajax-jquery-mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I call a Method in controller with ajax?

I'm using the following code but it gives an error :

```
public void DeleteUser(int no)
{
   if (Users!= null)
   {
      Users.RemoveAll(d => d.No == no);
   }
}
```

ajax code :

```
$.ajax({ 
    data: { no: id }, 
    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteUser", "UserController")', 
    complete: function (xhr, status) { 
        alert(status); // status = error    
    }
});
```

---

Answer (score 0):

First I would remove the controller from the Url.Action parameter. 
It is resolved using naming conventions so you never have to specify the controller name.

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '@Url.Action("DeleteUser", "User")',
      data: { no: id }, 
      success:function(result){
        // success code
       }
    });
```

I would also make sure you specify that DeleteUser is a post I.e.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public void DeleteUser(int no)
```

You also need to attach the event to a button or some other element within a document ready load I.e.

```
 $(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){  
      // the above ajax code 
      });
    });
```

Failing the above you need to debug using a combination of your browser's dubugger, console and requests made with something like fiddler.

It's worth investing time to learn how to debug like this as it is much easier to identify syntax errors and if you are actually hitting your controller.